# Javascript String Assignment Operators

Tags: javascript, operators, assignment-operator

How come I can use `+=` on a string, but I cannot use `-=` on it?

For example...

```
var test = "Test";
var arr = "&#8660;"

test += arr;
alert(test);  // Shows "Test&#8660;"

test -= arr;
alert(test);  // Shows "NaN"
```

Comment: Note: I am no dummy; I know you cannot "subtract" a string.  Somebody asked me this and I was not sure how to respond, so I am posting it here.

Comment: The `+` operator is the concatenation operator when one of the operands is a string.

Comment: Only two operators are defined for strings: `+` and `+=` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_Javascript_1.5_Reference#Operators)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is - it isn't defined to work with strings.

Longer answer: if you try the subtraction operator on two strings, it will first cast them to numbers and then perform the arithmetic.

```
"10" - "2" = 8
```

If you try something that is non-numeric, you get a NaN related error:

```
"AA" - "A" = NaN
```

Answer (score 7):

Because the `+` operator concatenates strings, but the `-` operator only subtracts numbers from each other.

As to the why -- probably because it is difficult to determine what people want to do when they subtract strings from each other.

For example:

```
"My string is a very string-y string" - "string"
```

What should this do?

Answer (score 3):

As all said, the `-=` operator is not overloaded to work with Strings, it only works with Numbers.

If you try to use it with strings, the operator will try to convert both operands to `Number`, that is why you are getting `NaN`, because:

```
isNaN(+"foo"); // true
```

To get rid of the `arr` content on your `test` string, you can [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) it:

```
var test = "Test",
    arr = "&#8660;"

test += arr;
alert(test);  // Shows "Test&#8660;"

test = test.replace(arr, ""); // replace the content of 'arr' with "" on 'test'
alert(test);  // Shows "Test"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the minus sign is not a valid String operator, whereas the plus sign is overloaded to handle both Numbers (addition operator) and Strings (concatenation operator).

What results were you hoping to get from this?

Comment: Hoping the "decrement" operator would behave like a substring and rip out what was previously appended.

Comment: But even with numbers the minus sign is not "decrement", that's minus-minus `--`. Minus-equals `-=` is just a convenience operator that's a compound operator analagous to the expression `a = a - b`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, programming languages don't define subtraction for strings.  += isn't really addition in the first place, it's concatenation.

Comment: php is a lot better for dealing with strings

Answer (score 0):

Because the +(plus sign) is also the string concatenation operator, while the -(minus sign) only applies to subtraction. If JavaScript can append 2 strings together it won't complain, but if you try to subtract 2 strings, it just doesn't make any sense.